# Does not exists in the given context

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax, html-helper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpjA8.png)

```
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var stdid = item.Studentid;
    var rows = "<tr>"
    + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.Studentid + "</td>"
    + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.StudentName + "</td>"
    + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + item.StudentAddress + "</td>"
    + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" 
    + '@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Studentid })'   
    + "</td>"
```

I am displaying Studentid in first column but in the fourth column, when its combined with the html helper (It is saying item is not defined in the given context) item.Studentid is not showing up in @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Studentid }) but it is working in above lines of code. You can see the image of my problem by clicking in the above link. Thanks

is it syntax error or i have to use some other html helper

Answer (score 0):

The ActionLink HTML Helper method executes when the Razor page is processed on the server. The Razor page doesn't have any context as to what the `item` variable is. The `item` variable is defined as a client-side (JavaScript) variable, not a server-side Razor page declared variable.

Your code is written in a way that it's attempting to execute the `ActionLink` method on the client side when the jQuery `$.each(data, function (i, item)...)`  iterator is executed in the AJAX `success` callback.

Your success callback is building an HTML string so you need to add the anchor element as a string while JavaScript is executing on the client:

```
+ "<td class='prtoducttd'>" 
+ "<a href='/edit/" + item.Studentid + "'>Edit</a>"   
+ "</td>"
```

Or using the string [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax for the anchor tag that may be better for code readability:

```
`<a href='/edit/${item.Studentid}'>Edit</a>`
```